# jQuery - Dynamically amend Input name with multiple dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden-field, square-bracket

I have an input field which looks something like this...

```
<input type='hidden' name='myInput[1][sausages][0][]' value='123' />
```

I need to change the value in the third set of square brackets when a user clicks on a button...

so something like

```
$("a.mylink").click( function() {
    $(this).siblings('input[name*=myInput]')..... CHANGE THE 0 to 1 in the third set of square brackets...
});
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$('input').attr('name',$('input').attr('name').replace(/\[\d+](?!.*\[\d)/, '[1]'))
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P6CY7/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace the value like so:

```
var name = $('input [name*=myInput]').attr('name');
name.replace(/]$/, 'new value]');
$('input [name*=myInput]').attr('name', name);
```

The new value can be any number
This regex replaces the last bracket with a new value: newvalue ]

Or if you want to change the 2nd to last bracket you can use this regex:

```
name.replace(/]\[\]$/, 'new value][]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    var name = $('input[name*=myInput]').attr('name');
    var indexOfThirdBracket = name.indexOf('[', name.indexOf('sausages')) + 1;
    name = name.substring(0, indexOfThirdBracket) + '1' + name.substring(indexOfThirdBracket + 1);
    $('input[name*=myInput]').attr('name', name);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3A592/

**UPDATE**

Solution without hard code value 'sausages'

```
var name = $('input[name*=myInput]').attr('name');
var parts = name.split('[');
parts[3] = parts[3].replace('0', '1');
name = parts.join('[');
$('input[name*=myInput]').attr('name', name);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/56rtG/

Comment: Using regexp much more better It doesn't depend on hard code value like in this sample.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
var counter = 1;
  $('a.mylink').click(function(){
  $(':text').attr('value', 'myInput[1][sausages][' + counter++ + '][]');
});
```